# How do I find the number of buys and sells within the last 24 hours for a specific ERC-20 token?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20, etherscan

I found this API that can give the the list of 'normal' transactions for a smart contract given the address for example Shiba Inu token:

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x95ad61b0a150d79219dcf64e1e6cc01f0b64c4ce&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YOURAPIKEY
```

Is there a way to get the # of buys and sells within a specific time frame? I need this for an app I'm building similar to how PooCoin or other sites can build a chart and have a panel that has buy and sell orders for that specific token.

Is there a way to get this data from an API call?